# fwrite is not sending out what I want in buffer

Tags: c, file, networking, download, fwrite

I'm trying to make it where when the user types "L" the LIST command runs and displays all the files available to download, but when I run it, after typing L, the program prints out "eetings". I think I am not correctly using the recv(), send(), or fwrite() commands, am I missing something? Further note when I type

```
ncat 65.19.178.177 1234
```

in the command line, it prints out "+OK Greetings", but when i type "L" in the program, it prints "eetings" so I think it's taking from that somehow.

```
void menu()
{
 printf("L) List files\n");
 printf("D) Download a file\n");
 printf("Q) Quit\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  struct sockaddr_in sa;
  int sockfd;

  sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
  sa.sin_port = htons(1234);
  inet_pton(AF_INET,"65.19.178.177", &sa.sin_addr);

  sockfd = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  if (sockfd == -1)
  {
   fprintf(stderr, "Can't create socket\n");
   exit(3);
  }

  int res = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa));
  if (res == -1)
  {
  fprintf(stderr, "can't connect\n");
  exit(2);
  }

  char buff[1000];
  size_t rsize;
  int resultcode;

  //Get treeting from server. Expecting 220
  rsize = recv(sockfd, buff, 1000, 0);
  sscanf(buff, "%d", &resultcode);

  if (buff[0]=='+')
  {
  printf("Success\n");
  }
  else
  {
   printf("Failed: Didn't get 220\n");
  }

while(1)
{
  menu();
  char *choice = readline("Choice: ");

  switch(choice[0])
  {
   case 'l':
   case 'L':
  //Handle L case
   sprintf(buff, "LIST");
   send(sockfd, buff, strlen(buff), 0);
   while ((rsize = recv(sockfd, buff, 1000, 0)) > 0)
   {
     fwrite(buff, rsize, 1, stdout);
   }
   close(sockfd);
   break;
```

Comment: [sigh] debugger - what is really in buf after the recv() call?  You should not just ignore rsize.

Comment: i dont know what you mean by debugger, im sorry, this is an intro C class

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that's what is happening (and I think that's what @Martin James meant):

In your initial `recv()` your don't check for the value of `rsize` but are happy if `buff[0] == '+'` afterwards. But you can't be sure that you've received the complete greeting by a single call of `recv()`, maybe just `"+OK Gr"` and the rest is still waiting to be received.

Now you send your command, but before you can receive the command's results, you will get the rest of the initial message, which is `"eetings"`

What you should so is something like that:

```
int received = 0;
int expected = strlen( "+OK Greetings" ); 

rsize = recv(sockfd, buff, 1000, 0);
if( resize <= 0 || buff[0] != '+' ) {
    // do some error handling and exit
    ..
}
received = rsize;
while( received < expected ) {
    rsize = recv(sockfd, buff+received, 1000-received, 0);
    if( resize <= 0 ) {
        // do some error handling and exit
        ..
    }
    received += rsize;
}
```

Calling `sscanf()` doesn't make sense to me, because according to your question, you don't receive a numeric value. Is that correct?

P.S.: 
if you don't have access to a 'real debugger', you can always add some `printf()` statements to your code to see what is happening, just like:

```
rsize = recv(sockfd, buff, 1000, 0);
printf( "recv() returns %d\n", rsize );
```

Comment: yeah, just did that, and i got it to return 6. do i have to set rsize to 0, after case "L"?

Comment: No, but it shows that my guesses seem to be right. you've received 6 bytes only --> `"+OK Gr"`. I will edit my answer to show you what you can do.

Comment: tysm I appreciate it, and yes I was getting that string, I gave 1000 bytes in the recv function though, so I am a bit confused on why it only allocated 6 bytes.

Comment: It hasn't 'allocated' 6 bytes, it has **read** 6 bytes. In a socket communication you must never expect to read all data with a single `recv()`. You must always have loops similar to the one in my example.

Comment: Ok so it's now printing the whole greeting thanks, but upon typing "L" I still get ERR illegal command

Comment: sorry to hear that; have you tried calling "LIST" by `ncat`? From that point on it becomes quite difficult to help without knowing the server

Comment: As I've already said - hard to tell without knowing the server. I've got no access to `ncat` to try it out, maybe newlines are part of the messages? (you don't send them).

Comment: i found the problem I had to do LIST\n, not LIST, my original code is fine